# Debian - Routing multiple virtual interfaces

Tags: linux-networking

I've a Debian computer with multiple external IPs (7 in total), each IP has its own virtual interface (`eth0:1`,`eth0:2`, etc...)

I would like to know: how can I configure routing so each time I ssh to a specific IP it goes out from that IP instead of the default (`eth0`).

Example:

> SSH to IP `1.1.1.2`
>   -> `ip ro get 8.8.8.8` 
>   -> shows `1.1.1.1` as source

I know it is possible doing it with `iproute2` tools. Can you guys give me a little help here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use aliases, just add the IP addresses to the interface:

```
ip addr add 1.1.1.2/32 dev eth0
```

etc.

If you always want to reach 8.8.8.8 with a source IP of 1.1.1.2, then do this:

```
ip route add 8.8.8.8/32 via $GATEWAY dev eth0 src 1.1.1.2
```

Replace `$GATEWAY` with the default gateway. It's that simple...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i need that each IP can go to any random IP (using each IP as source), not only one.

Comment: That's not quite what the question is asking. But have you considered ssh's -b option for binding the source address, if it is in fact ssh that you'd be using (as you state in the question).

Comment: Wurtel, thanks again for your answer, I'm trying to establish a tunnel between my computer and one of those available IP addresses, each time I SSH to an IP ( per example 1.1.1.2), the default outgoing IP its always 1.1.1.1, that's why I asked if there's a way to create a special route so each time I ssh to each IP, its that IP that goes out. The ssh -b option only allow you to bind the local source, I plan to use the remote, can you give me a help on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're not quite understanding how routing works; the fact that you're connecting to one of those extra IP addresses has nothing to do with what outgoing IP address is used when you then make an outgoing connection. The new connection has no knowledge of any earlier connection, even if that connection is the one over which the command is given to make the new connection. The only relevant thing is possibly the source address (if bound to it e.g. via `ssh -b`) and the destination IP.